# datetime.now() returns UTC time on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-datetime

I recently deployed my flask application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everything seemed fine until I realized that datetime.datetime.now() is returning UTC time(7 hours ahead of local time for me) rather than local time. It doesn't do this when I run it on localhost. What would the issue be and what would be the steps I should take to mitigate this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practice to configure servers in UTC. So it is normal that `datetime.datetime.now()` gives you UTC time.

You can use the [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) library to manage time zones in your code, to transition dates to your local timezone when needed.

It is really useful to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/3100523) about date and timezones best practices to have a broader view about how to manage the interaction between your server's time and your local timezone.